# Handling Unknown JSON Properties with Jackson

Tags: json, jackson

For deserializing json with unknown field into an object there's @JsonAnySetter.

But what if I read such json into my object, modify some known fields and write it back to json?
The unknown properties will be lost.

How do I handle such cases? Is it possible to map an object or do I have to read the data into a JsonNode or Map?

Comment: http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/JACKSON-292

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unmarshalling into a custom java class has its advantages and disadvantages. It's gives you nice static typing, but it's well, static. The javadoc for `@JsonAnySetter` suggests that it's similar to JAXB's `@XmlAnyElement`, but unlike `@XmlAnyElement`, the data objects don't contain naming information, so it's a one-way street.

if you need to handle dynamic JSON streams, then you need to bite the bullet and use `Map` or `JsonNode`.

Answer (score 3):

It is now possible to use `@JsonAnyGetter` to provide a method which allows serialization of dynamic properties:

```
@JsonAnyGetter
public Map<String, String> getDynamicProperties() {
    return dynamicProperties; // a field like this exists
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There's this RFE for Jackson: http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/JACKSON-292 to add such a feature. Makes total sense when you think about it.

Comment: and the feature itself will go in 1.6 when it gets released